# Comfortably input and edit data stored via Data module

Tags: views, 6, forms, ajax

I am building an application that stores its data in the Data module.  Displaying or querying stuff works well, simple modifications via VBO also worked.  However editing and inserting new records is problematic.

In other words, the underlying API works well and everything connected to it.  I am looking for fancy ways to input and edit data.

Do I have to write all input forms and logic by hand?  Or alternatively write Ajax handlers to include in Views (like in Data Taxonomy)?

Is there any module that can speed up the creating of input forms for the Data module?

Comment: probably not, see http://drupal.org/node/524270

Comment: probably http://drupal.org/project/autoadmin

Comment: Thank you very much for the link to autoadmin.  I have been looking at several possibilities from time to time, but never came across that module.  It does not seem "fancy", but it supports one-to-many relationships, which will get me started right away.